# Over 6 seconds to receive data from server. Screenshot included, can't find why. Wordpress, W3TC, Cloudflare, etc

Tags: performance, wordpress, caching, cloudflare

I am using cloudflare, W3 Total Cache, and amazon s3. I am using database, page, object, and browser caching via W3TC.

What causes the delay in receiving data from the server as seen here? This is incredible, I feel it might have been faster without W3TC installed.

Screenshot of headers
[image]

Comment: *Does* it get faster when you deactivate WPTC? Either way, this is going to be very hard to debug for us without access to the server.... you'll need to give some info, like what kind of environment the site is running on.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://wpengineer.com/1176/analyze-wordpress-performance-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts.

It looks to me like there are two 404s on the home page, so probably good to get them fixed:

http://cdn.thedigitalhippies.com/wp-content/themes/sahifa/fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.woff
http://cdn.thedigitalhippies.com/wp-content/themes/sahifa/fonts/BebasNeue-webfont.eot?

There are 20 odd CSS files on the page and plenty of js files. I think you would get good improvement if you combined and minified these into single CSS and JS files with somthing like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-minify/

Hope this helps!